# printing the reverse of an integer array using recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion

I am not able to understand how I am getting a garbage value in output . Can someone explain me the flow . Thank you .

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rev(int *ptr){

  if(*ptr) {
    rev(ptr+1);
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);

  }
}

int main(){      

  int arr[]={4,2,3,1,5};  
  rev(arr);  
  return 0;  
}
```

output -

```
32764   
5
1
3 
2  
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base condition is not correct. You recurse until a 0 is found in the array but it doesn't have one.

You have perhaps (incorrectly) assumed that there's a 0 after the end of the array. But this is not true in C. Your program has [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as per C standard.

If you need to print the entire array, then pass the size as well:

```
void rev(int *ptr, size_t size){    
    if(size) {
        rev(ptr+1, --size);
        printf("%d\n",*ptr);
    }
}

int main(){

    int arr[]={4,2,3,1,5};
    rev(arr, sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so, technically this will hold good for printing the reverse of a string as it terminates with '\0'

Answer (score 2):

Your relying on `if (*ptr)` being 0 to block the recursion is not going to end well. Arrays in C are not terminated with zero automatically. Formally, the behaviour of your program is *undefined* as you will attempt to read memory past the end of the array.

The normal way of dealing with this is to either pass the array length, or use a special value to signal the end of the array.